# Run code on file open in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to run some code in Sublime Text every time I open a file.  Is there any way of doing this?

The background, if you want more context:  I recently started using Sublime Text as my main editor, and although I love having Vim mode available through the Vintageous plug-in, I just want it to be ***available***, not forcing its way into being turned on every time I open a file.

The author does not seem open to adding an option for being turned off by default--which is entirely okay: I'm not trying to be critical of his choices, and I'm glad he's made his code available to me--so it occurred to me that Sublime Text might offer some way of running some code every time you open a file.  If so, I would simply run something that sets the mode to the ***normal*** Sublime Text mode (as opposed to Vim's "normal" mode).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - can you explain in greater detail what exactly you're trying to do? If you'd like to activate Vintageous (or any other plugin), you can use the Command Palette and search for `Package Control: Enable Package` and a list of the plugins in the `"ignored_packages"` array will be shown. If you'd like to disable it later on, just use `Package Control: Disable Package`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what I can mention that I didn't already explain.   I don't want to activate the plugin—it's already active, but it's forcing me into Vim mode, and I want to ***not*** be in Vim mode when I open a new document.  So I want to run some code to put me in the normal editing mode for Sublime.  And the command palette is used manually.  This needs to be automatic or it has no value, since I can instead just use <kbd>esc</kbd>.  (But remembering to always hit <kbd>esc</kbd> is a giant pain, and exactly what I'm trying to avoid.)

Comment: So you want new documents to be opened in Insert mode instead of Command mode?

Comment: Yes, that's my goal, which forms the contextual background of the question.  But the question is simply: how can I run some code in Sublime as soon as a new document/file is opened?

Comment: Oh, OK. I'll write up a quick answer.

Comment: (I didn't use the term "command mode" because AFAIK that actually refers to Vim's mode where you enter things after the `:`.  Vim's terminology is confusing, and the mismatch between Vim's idea of "normal" and Sublime's idea of "normal" makes it even more confusing.  In my attempts to be clear and avoid ambiguity, it's possible that I made it even more confusing.  :/   )

Answer (score 2):

You can run code in response to various events by creating a [plugin](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) and subclassing [`sublime_plugin.EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener). The methods you would be most interested in are `on_load()` and `on_new()`. From there, you can either run an existing command, or you can make your own in a different class (probably subclassing [`sublime_plugin.TextCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand)).